# How to split text by character in Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am currently using this code:

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.split("",expand=True,n=20)
```

Error:

`ValueError: split() requires a non-empty pattern match.`

The error is at this line inside Pandas code

```
-> 1387             f = lambda x: regex.split(x, maxsplit=n)
```

It works on some Python environment but not all, even if Pandas version is same

I am getting this error in some python enviorment such as Google colab. Probably related to Regex version. I was wondering, is there any alternative to this line that is equally fast?

Comment: could you share a sample of the dataframe, with expected output? pandas str split has a maxsplit option as well (n)

Comment: Expected output is basically split by each character. Like ['s','t','a','c','k']

Answer (score 2):

first param of `split` is optional if you are not adding any meaningful data to split then why don't you just ignore this param.

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.split(expand=True,n=20)
```

by default, it will split by spaces

if you want to split by every character then write a meaningful regular expression to split on

if you want to split by any number or character then use like

```
df['names'].str.split(r"[a-zA-Z0-9]",expand=True, n=20)
```

if you want to split by anything then

```
 df['names'].str.split(r".?",expand=True, n=20)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you tell me the regular ecpression to split by character?

Comment: any specific character you want to use for split or any character from A to Z?

Comment: All characters actually, not just A to Z. Numbers, non english words, emoji etc